# Combine 2 filters for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two actions that work separately, but the feature I am trying to make, required to combine them in one function with conditional logic.

Diplay "Free" when product price is '0' or empty:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 10, 2 );    
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {
  if( $product->get_price() == 0 ||  $product->get_price() == '') {        
      $custom_text = '<p class="label_not_available">Free</p>';          
  }
return $price . $custom_text;
}
```

Change Currency Symbol:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 2 );    
function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency ) {
    if ( 'USD' === $currency ) {
        return 'USD';
    }
        return $symbols;
}
```

Need to combine them in one, with following logic:
--- IF product price = '0' or '' ==>>> Override $symbols value, with custom text.

I have tried to go with code like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_currency_symbol', 10, 4 );
function change_currency_symbol( $symbols, $currency, $price, $product) {
    if( $product->get_price() == '') {    
        $currency = 'THB';
        return $currency;
    }
}
```

but only white screen is appearing instead of the web-site, when I run it.

would be really appreciate for any suggestion, what I do wrong and the way to make it work.

target - to replace currency symbol in the plugin that display woocommerce grid, because it always show currency character, even for when price is empty, would be better to replace it with the word "FREE".

Comment: Do you happen to know which filter runs first? This is a perfect use-case for using a PHP class, storing the value of the price so it's available to the symbol function, where you can then check if it's 0, and return nothing..... (NOTE: white screen is because you have not enabled debugging - in the wp-config.php file, set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`....

Comment: The filter 'woocommerce_get_price_html' is applied after the filter 'woocommerce_currency_symbol' is applied and allows you to change the HTML of the price so you can change anything in that HTML including the currency symbol. I.e., you don't need to use the filter 'woocommerce_currency_symbol'.